# Microsoft Planner API is not retuning user Display Names

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to access Microsoft Planner data through Graphs API from SharePoint(Online) and getting success response message also.
But the problem is "DisplayName" field is null for all user sections in JSON data (such as createdBy, assignedBy,completedBy etc)

Example :

```js
"assignments": {
    "309249ab-fe3e-4ed7-8d64-3c6187527437": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment",
        "assignedBy": {
            "user": { 
                "displayName": null,                    
                "id": "s33dfsdf-fe3e-4ed7-8d64-3c6187527437"
            }
        },
```

---

```js
"createdBy": {
    "user": {
        "displayName": null,
        "id": "fsdfsf-fe3e-4ed7-8d64-3c6187527437"
    }
```

---

```js
"completedBy": {
    "user": {
        "displayName": null,
        "id": "fsdlhfdals-fe3e-4ed7-8d64-3c6187527437"
    }
}
```

How to get the display names from Planner API?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior. I suspect this is a bug and I'll raise a flag to have this investigated. I have confirmed that the `id` being returned so a (not-so-great) workaround here is to place a second call to the `/user` endpoint with that `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Planner data does not include display names. Display names need to be obtained separately. Group membership information for the containing group (`groups/<id>/members`) will contain display name (and more) information for user ids returned in plan and task information, for all users who are still members of the group. The id of the group that contains the plan is specified by the **owner** field of the plan. Remaining users' information can be obtained by reading those users directly (`users/<id>`).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.